# Incomplete cycle with "Cycles" modifier in graph editor

Tags: animation, modifiers, graph-editor, nla-editor

I perform the task on the walking man, I use the loop modifier to loop the animation in the graph editor. This is not in the task, but I am interested. Is there a way to make the modifier work not from the very beginning, but from a certain period of time? For example, if my character didn't start walking right away and did something before that. I tried to create actions in NLA, but there you can't cut the actions from the beginning and the end, only stretch them. How to do it correctly?
[image]

Comment: You can stop a clip in the NLA: Open the N panel > Strip > Action Clip > Frame End

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop a clip in the *NLA*: Open the *N panel > Strip > Action Clip > Frame End*:

[image]

You can also choose the start and end of the cycle in the *N* panel of the *Graph Editor > Modifiers > Cycle >* activate *Restrict Frame Range*:

[image]